# How to make NUnit 3 test adapter and console runner read a specific application config file

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a couple of test assemblies that depends on a shared configuration file. In NUnit 2.6 it was possible to load a "X.nunit" project file in the console runner where after the console runner would load "X.config" automatically. Apparently that does not happen in NUnit 3.5 - so how can I force the console runner to use a specific config file?

The same applies to the test adapter: in NUnit 2.6 it was possible to load a "X.nunit" project file in the GUI-runner. That is not possible with Nunit 3.5 as project files are not (yet) supported in the GUI. So apparently the way to go is to use the VS 2015 test adapter to run tests from inside Visual Studio - but then we have the same problem again of not being able to load the right configuration file. Is there a way to specify a specific configuration file when running tests from inside VS?

Comment: Apparently it is supposed to be done as described here: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Configuration-Files but it does not work for me. See https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1893

Comment: FYI - the issue you filed with nunit is being worked on. It looks as if the docs (taken from V2) are incorrect. However, your issue never mentioned the VS adapter, which is another matter entirely. Basically, whatever runner is being used has to decide on the config file and pass it to the framework. The framework then has to honor that request. Since the framework is ignorant of nunit project files, it can only pick out a default config based on the name of each assembly unless over-ridden by a setting from the runner.